# Односвязный упорядоченный список

Tags: c++

Составить программу, которая:

- обеспечивает первоначальный ввод целых чисел и формирует из них  упорядоченного списка;
- затем  удалить из списка отрицательные числа и удвоить положительные;
- исходный и преобразованный список  должны быть выведены на экран;

Сам я выполнил только первый пункт и то не до конца, ибо не знаю как упорядочить

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define list struct spisok

list
{int info;
list* next;
};
list* head;

list* first(int d)
{list *t=new list;
t->next=0;
t->info=d;
return t;
};

void insert (list** s, int x)
{
    list* t=*s;
    list* p=0;
    list *r;
    while(t!=0)
    { p=t;
    t=t->next;
    }

    r=first(x);
    if(p==0)
        *s=r;
    else
        p->next=r;

};

void display(list *s)
{ list *t=s;
while(t)
{
    cout<<t->info;

    t=t->next;
}
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{int x;
cout<<"Vvedite 4isla"<<endl;
cin>>x;
head=first(x);
do
{cin>>x;
insert(& head,x);
}
while(x!=0);
display(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: для второго пункта: пройдитесь по списку (знаете, как?), тестируйте значение элемента и либо модифицируйте его (для положительных), либо удаляйте (для отрицательных). вам понадобится процедура удаления из списка.

Comment: вот я как раз и не знаю как пройтись по списку. наверное надо через while()? и функцию удаления я тоже не знаю как написать.

Comment: ага, например, через while. функцию удаления вы уж как-то сами, это основы. спросите у своего учителя, в конце-концов.

Comment: да в том-то и дело, что учитель не очень хороший попался. у нас вообще одна лекция в две недели и материал очень сжатый,а на практике учитель почти вечно отсутствует. если не сложно, подскажите пожалуйста хорошую литературу для начинающих

Comment: @SS7, insert у Вас явно неправильный. Там все таки надо бы сравнивать элементы списка с новым и вставлять его в нужное место.

В результате получите упорядоченный список.

--

Я бы изменил прототип insert() и все станет просто.

    list *insert(list *head, list *newitem);

Тогда ввод данных и построение списка выглядит так

    list *head = 0, *item;
    while (item = get_item())
       head = insert(head, item);

Начало insert тривиально

    list *insert (list *head, list *item)
    {
       if (!head)
          return item;
       ...
    }

Посмотрите, как все упрощается. Дальше сами.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подсказку!